# How stop file upload event using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to stop file upload event when I upload the file more than 5mb or if my file extension is not `.jpg` or `.png`. I found a code but when I try to upload the invalid file type then it only gives me alerts that I have uploaded the wrong file but it does not cancel the event.
Here is the code:

```
<script>
function checkFile(fieldObj)
{
    var FileName  = fieldObj.value;
    var FileExt = FileName.substr(FileName.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
    var FileSize = fieldObj.files[0].size;
    var FileSizeMB = (FileSize/5485760).toFixed(2);

    if ( (FileExt != "png" && FileExt != "jpg") || FileSize>5485760)
    {
        var error = "File type : "+ FileExt+"\n\n";
        error += "Size: " + FileSizeMB + " MB \n\n";
        error += "Please make sure your file is in png or jpg format and less than 5 MB.\n\n";
        
        alert(error);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

and here is html code:

```
 <input type="file"onchange="checkFile(this)"name='sec_2_img'>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to clear the value of 'sec_2_img'. You do this by adding `fieldObj.value = "";` after `alert(error)` and before `return false;`. This will remove the file name from `sec_2_img` and force user to select a new one while still showing the message so user knows what to do.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Don't use alerts, they are annoying and the browsers will block them pretty fast, so your users won't get any message anymore.
Use a modal window or add a styled element with the error-message somewhere into your form.

2.) If you need to have a valid file to submit this form, you have to add a event-handler to the submit-event of the form and stop the trasmission.

3.) your check for file-extension is case-sensitive, this might give you problems on windows, and your calculation of the fileSize is wrong.