# ng-file-upload : Changing format from Custom files to All files, it accepts blocked file types to upload

Tags: angularjs, html, ng-file-upload

I have following code which accepts only image and pdf files, but if I change Format from file selection window(i think it's provided by Chrome itself) Custom files to All files, it's accepting all file formats including zip folders.

```
<button type="button" class="btn-submit upload for-hover smooth-hover"
        data-prod-idx="{{index}}" data-prod-id="{{prod.ProductId}}"
        ng-click="vm.onUpload($event, index, prod.ProductId)"
        ngf-select="vm.uploadAttachments($event, $files, $invalidFiles)"
        multiple accept="application/pdf, image/*" 
        ngf-capture="'camera'"
        ngf-max-size="5MB">Upload Documents
</button>
```

How to stop uploading files except for image and pdf?(No JQuery please, for all browsers)

I have tried using different values in accept, but that's not helping me.

Comment: If you want to be absolutely sure a user is not going to upload something other than an image or PDF, you will want to throw an error server-side. For the front-end, see the following SO question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654073/how-stop-file-upload-event-using-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654073/how-stop-file-upload-event-using-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How stop file upload event using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654073/how-stop-file-upload-event-using-javascript)

Comment: Use the [file.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type) property of each [File object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) to determine if it is an inappropriate type. In the `uploadAttachments` function, skip the upload if the type is inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [file.type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type) property of each [File object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) to determine if it is an inappropriate type. In the `uploadAttachments` function, skip the upload if the type is inappropriate.

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/cXPr9hsClEKH1dJbVrG2?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",['ngFileUpload'])
.controller("ctrl", function () {
  vm = this;
  vm.uploadAttachments = (event, fileList) => {
    console.log("fileList.length=", fileList.length);
    var validList = fileList.filter( f => {
      if (f.type.startsWith("application/pdf")) return true;
      if (f.type.startsWith("image/")) return true;
      console.log("skipping", f.name);
      return false;
    })
    console.log("validList.length=",validList.length);
  };
})
```

```html
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/ng-file-upload/dist/ng-file-upload-all.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
    <button type="button" class="btn-submit upload for-hover smooth-hover"
        data-prod-idx="{{index}}" data-prod-id="{{prod.ProductId}}"
        ng-click="vm.onUpload($event, index, prod.ProductId)"
        ngf-select="vm.uploadAttachments($event, $files, $invalidFiles)"
        multiple accept="application/pdf, image/*" 
        ngf-capture="'camera'"
        ngf-max-size="5MB">Upload Documents
    </button>
  </body>
```